# Chose math operation with condition

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have maybe a strange problem, but i'll try to describe it.
I have an expression with two math operations "%" and "/":

```
int a = x / y;
int a = x % y;
```

And i have a parameter of a function, where i check, what Math operator (% or /) i have to implement for this expression. So, it there a way to select operator for expression **without duplication of a code**.

```
int a = parameter ? x / y: x % y;
```

or

```
if (parameter) a = x/y; else a = x%y;
```

that's wrong for me.

It there a way to use something like this:

```
int a = x (parameter ? / : %) y;
```

Problem with code vision:

```
items.Where((item, index) => 
                    settings.cbl_Direction == Direction.Horizontal ?
                        index / (int)settings.cbl_RepeatColumns == i 
                    :
                        index % (int)settings.cbl_RepeatColumns == i)
```

Comment: Why is `int a = parameter ? x / y: x % y;` not good enough?

Comment: I think you're exagerating a little :) I don't think `int a = parameter ? x / y: x % y;` is wrong at all

Comment: That's look like not very good for code vision:                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in items.Where((item, index) => 
                    settings.cbl_Direction == Direction.Horizontal ?
                        index / (int)settings.cbl_RepeatColumns == i 
                    :
                        index % (int)settings.cbl_RepeatColumns == i))

Comment: "that's wrong for me." Why? I think you are complicating something that is easy. Are your sure your not splitting hairs here.

Comment: it actually is an interesting question.

Comment: @codesparkle - I disagree, it's not going to get any simpler. It's as simple as basic programming.

Comment: @FSou: You could remove the duplicated code in your edit by using an anonymous type or a [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx). But that has nothing to do with the question you actually asked.

Comment: Ok, mb really 'The best is the enemy of the good'. Thk u all.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> div = (m, n) => m / n;
Func<int, int, int> mod = (m, n) => m % n;

int a = (parameter ? div : mod)(x, y);
```

In my opinion this slightly increases the code complexity, so it might be better to stick with what you already have.

Comment: +1 Cute, but still not much different than using `?:` with inline statements.

Comment: So, my code should be like this: items.Where((item, index) => 
                    (settings.cbl_Direction == Direction.Horizontal ? div : mod)(index, (int)settings.cbl_RepeatColumns) == i) :)

Comment: @FSou1: You *could* do that, but I probably wouldn't do it. Instead consider using a `let` clause to remove the duplicated expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx

Comment: Ok, i'll check let clause. Thx.

Comment: But why? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I think I'd either cry or hit the roof if I found something like this in any of our production code!

Comment: @LukeH: Agreed, this is truly ridiculous, just use a simple if. The author mentions about removing code duplication, but that's taking the concept to a stratospheric level.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is true because there is not any way to write this and also i have not see any other way. so use this two way,

```
int a = parameter ? x / y: x % y;
```

or

```
if (parameter) a = x/y; else a = x%y;
```

this 2 methods are good and enough to reduce code...

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
if (parameter) a = x/y; else a = x%y;
```

Unless you have a very compelling reason not to do so, you are only introducing complexity for no good reason. 
Software is complex as it is without introducing needless complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution, but I spent to time to write the code so I might aswell post it:

Define these two:

```
private const string ClassString1 =
        @"
    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        public static class MyClass
        {
            public static int InvokeMath(int x, int y)
            {
                return ";
    private const string ClassString2 = @";
            }
        }
    }";
```

Method that does the magic:

```
public static int MethodOperation(int x, int y, string @operator)
    {
        var sharpCom = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var results = sharpCom.CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true, GenerateExecutable = false }, ClassString1 + string.Format("x {0} y", @operator) + ClassString2);
        return (int)results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First().GetMethods().First().Invoke(null, new object[] { x, y });
    }
```

Used like this:

```
var divide = MethodOperation(2, 2, "/");
var mod = MethodOperation(2, 2, "%");
```

Total code reuse while sacrificing readablity, speed, and just about everything else you can sacrifice!